# Writing to multiple identical devices, python USB, no serial number on device

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb, linux-device-driver, pyusb

I am working on controlling some relay cards from Python.  I can configure and control an individual relay card just fine (pyusb, python3.6 ubuntu 16.04). Using the standard methods to identify and configure the USB device.

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1a86, idProduct=0x7523)
```

However, I need to use multiple of the same type devices, and can find them just fine:

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1a86, idProduct=0x7523, find_all=True)
```

The problem arrives because the get_active_configuration() for both devices is identical.  I am able to query for the device bus and the device address, however, not sure how to use this USB connection information to identify the board and do a serial write function from within python using just the bus & address.

Note:  in my research both the [pyusb documentation](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst) and several other forum posts indicate using the usb connection bus & address to differentiate between multiple identical devices, so I believe that to be a valid approach, yet I'm not sure how to actually write code to do that since most other examples I have seen simply look to match up idVendor + idProduct.

Posting here the code I use now to access one device:

```
import time
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1a86, idProduct=0x7523)

if dev is None:
    raise ValueError("Device not found")

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
    dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)

cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]

ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)

assert ep is not None

# example relay hex serial command
cl_all = [0x3A, 0x46, 0x45, 0x30, 0x46, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x32, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x45, 0x33, 0x0D, 0x0A]

# example write operation
ep.write(cl_all)
```

So basically, dev basically picks up either one of the configurations, and if I use the find_all=True flag in usb.core.find, I can find both boards.  Just not sure how to address them separately if there is no serial number.  After looking into it, I think (but I'm not sure) that the second board's interface is then stored in cfg[(1,0)], but first, I haven't been able to implement it successfully, and secondly that wouldn't necessarily be permanent every time I booted up or the boards are plugged and unplugged.

Update / Edit:  After working on this card for another 20 hours or so, and corresponding with the manufacturer and some other folks working on the same problem (github link below), the conclusion I have is that the board doesn't support serialization.  I moved to an ethernet-based relay card, and although more expensive, was easily able to set a fixed IP addresss for each board and accomplish my objectives.  I don't believe this problem is solvable with the USB hardware problem that I have, and furthermore, the board fails to return a simple status (and I have two of these boards, so it isn't a single-device bug).

https://github.com/ondrej1024/crelay/issues/21

Comment: Show us the code you already have.

Comment: Sure, just pasted the code.